# NotificationListenerService.cancelNotification throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to cancel/remove a notification from the status bar, by using the [cancelNotification()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) method from within my `NotificationListenerService`, using the following code:

```
public final void mcancelNotification(String pkgn, String t, int i){
    cancelNotification(pkgn, t, i); //line 84
}
```

However I am getting a `NullPointerException`(see below) and after doing some tests I noticed that it was the `tag t` that was `null`.
This is how I got the `pkgn`, `t` and `i` values from within the `onNotificationPosted` method:

```
    packageName = sbn.getPackageName();
    tag = sbn.getTag();
    id = sbn.getId();
```

How can I remove the notification if the tag is equal to null? Am I missing something? Would really appreciate some help, thanks

NPE:

```
09-13 14:23:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(29456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 14:23:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(29456): Process: com.project.now, PID: 29456
09-13 14:23:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(29456): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 14:23:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(29456):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1471)
09-13 14:23:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(29456):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
09-13 14:23:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(29456):    at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.cancelNotificationFromListener(INotificationManager.java:469)
09-13 14:23:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(29456):    at android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService.cancelNotification(NotificationListenerService.java:116)
09-13 14:23:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(29456):    at com.project.now.NoLiSes.mcancelNotification(NoLiSes.java:84)
```

Comment: placecode for of com.project.now.NoLiSes.mcancelNotification.NoLiSes.java line 84

Comment: please post some more code... when your calling mcancelNotification(String pkgn, String t, int i)

Comment: @Imtiyaz line 84 is posted, I have edited my post and marked it in my code above

Comment: @sunil that is all there is to that method it should simply remove the notification. I call the method from another class of mine using an instance of the NLS class. I have checked the values (parameters) and all seems well apart from the tag t value, sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void cancelNotification(Context ctx, int notifyId) {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
    nMgr.cancel(notifyId);
}
```

//Cancel a previously shown notification.

```
cancel(String tag, int id)
```

//Inform the notification manager about dismissal of a single notification.

```
cancelNotification(String pkg, String tag, int id)
```

link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

```
public static final int FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
```

Added in API level 1

Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if the notification should be canceled when it is clicked by the user.

// Clear all notification

```
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nMgr.cancelAll();
```

but you can't cancel other apps notifications, thats not possible.

Comment: I tried the four lines you posted at the top, but I got a NullPointerException concerning the ctx ... I used getApplicationContext() instead of passing a ctx parameter through it. Why doesn't that work? Thanks for the help

Comment: please post the class from where your calling  mcancelNotification

Comment: I changed it to what the precise code you posted and now nothing seems to happen: no exception and no removal of the notification. If I understand correctly then the code you posted is used for my own notifications the ones I posted. While what I want to do is be able to remove any Notification, whether I was the one who posted it or not. Using the NLS which requires permission by the user. I appreciate the help anyway, thanks...correct me if I am wrong

Comment: see the edit you can cancel your own notifications using NotificationManager,but you can't cancel other apps notifications, thats not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

First of all, you must have only one instance of your NotificationListenerService. In my application I am to handle my notifications in singletone and work with them from many classes. This is part of my service:

```
    private ServiceListener listener;
    private NotificationsHolder holder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     packageManager = getPackageManager();
     holder = NotificationsHolder.getInstance();
     listener = holder;
     listener.registerService(this);
    }
```

The ServiceListener interface:

```
    public interface ServiceListener {
     void registerService(NotificationService service);
     void unregisterService();
    }
```

In NotificationsHolder class (it is a singletone):

```
    @Override
    public void registerService(NotificationService service) {
     this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterService() {
     service = null;
    }

    public NotificationService getService(){
     return service;
    }
```

And now, wherever I need to cancel notification, I do:

```
    holder = NotificationsHolder.getInstance();
    NotificationService service = holder.getService();
    service.cancelNotification (myNotification.getPackageName(), myNotification.getTag(), myNotification.getIndex());
```

It works